# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using MongoDB driver in intellij

Tags: java, mongodb, intellij-idea

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB database through jdbc in intellij,getting the error as

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
```

I have added the dependencies :

```
"org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "3.9.1",
"org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-sync" % "3.8.2"
```

Code is as follow:

```
public class PlainQueryRepository {
    Connection connection = null;
    public void createConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("mongo://127.0.0.1:27017/hybrid-flow");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to load SQLServer JDBC Driver");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) connection.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        PlainQueryRepository obj = new PlainQueryRepository();
        obj.createConnection();
    }

}
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: obviously  jvm cannot detect the mongodb driver during runtime,look at your runtime classpath if the class is present there

Comment: Basically, you have two different versions of the mongo dependencies.

Comment: Can you update the question and post the entire stack trace?

Comment: have you ran your mongodb server by mongod?

Comment: Now that I think a bit more about you should take @JaiDixit advice. The mongo db driver must not be on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different versions of the mongo dependencies.

One of these is referencing something in the other's compatible version that doesn't exist.

This

`"org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "3.9.1"
 "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-sync" % "3.8.2"`

Needs to be this 

 `"org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "3.9.1"
 "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-sync" % "3.9.1"`

or this

`"org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "3.8.2"
 "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-sync" % "3.8.2"`

Comment: Thanks,even after updating the version also i'm getting the same error

Comment: Did you clean and reload your dependencies?